# Accessing JSON in dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have this json

```
"delivery_order":{
      "created_at":{
         "0":"2020-01-27 00:00:)0",
         "1":"2020-07-04 00:00:00",
         "2":"2020-05-26 00:00:00",
      },
      "status":{
         "0":"delivery_completed",
         "1":"pending",
         "2":"pending",
      }
   },
```

in my code i store it like this

```
order_data = pd.DataFrame(data['delivery_order'])
```

my question is how do i access the 0 index on the json, so the json looks like this

```
"delivery_order":{
      "created_at":{
         "0":"2020-01-27 00:00:)0",
      },
      "status":{
         "0":"delivery_completed",
      }
   },
```

i tried this and this works

```
data['delivery_order']['created_at'][0]['status'][0]
```

but, how do i access the index without manually accessing it? because sometimes the data that sent from server looks like this

```
"delivery_order":{
      "status":{
         "0":"delivery_completed",
         "1":"pending",
         "2":"pending",
      },
      "created_at":{
         "0":"2020-01-27 00:00:)0",
         "1":"2020-07-04 00:00:00",
         "2":"2020-05-26 00:00:00",
      }
   },
```

so manually accessing it by index like this wont work

```
data['delivery_order']['created_at'][0]['status'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pandas use [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
# create df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['delivery_order'], orient='columns')
print(df)

            created_at              status
0  2020-01-27 00:00:)0  delivery_completed
1  2020-07-04 00:00:00             pending
2  2020-05-26 00:00:00             pending


# get value by index
index = 1
df.iloc[index].to_dict()
```